# Setting the SelectedItem for ComboBox component in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, selecteditem

I have been defined some `ComboBox` element:

```
<ComboBox Height="27" Margin="124,0,30,116" Name="cbProductDefaultVatRate" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Height="26" Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

and set the data source for component items of `VatRate` type:

```
private void ShowAllVatRates()
{
    cbProductDefaultVatRate.Items.Clear();
    cbProductDefaultVatRate.ItemsSource = new VatRateRepository().GetAll();
}
```

`VatRate` object has a property:

```
private Product SelectedProduct
{
    get; set;
}
```

where is a product contains `VatRate` as well:

```
SelectedProduct.DefaultVatRate
```

How to set `SelectedItem` property of ComboBox to `SelectedProduct.DefaultVatRate`?

```
// does not work!!!
cbProductDefaultVatRate.SelectedItem = SelectedProduct.DefaultVatRate;
```

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the actual object instance behind `SelectedProduct.DefaultVatRate` is the same instance as the one that is part of the list returned by `new VatRateRepository().GetAll()` or `object.Equals()` must return `true` for the two instances.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! While I write as follows:
foreach (var item in cbProductDefaultVatRate.Items)
{
 if (Equals(((VatRate)item).Value, SelectedProduct.DefaultVatRate.Value))
  cbProductDefaultVatRate.SelectedItem = item;
}

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to get a TwoWay binding like this?

```
    <ComboBox Height="27" Margin="124,0,30,116" Name="cbProductDefaultVatRate" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct.DefaultVatRate, Mode=TwoWay}>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Height="26" Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: `SelectedItem` is TwoWay bound by default (BindsTwoWayByDefault). So you don't need to explitly redefine that in the xaml binding expression.